# ¿Cuándo usar [set]?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, desambiguación-etiquetas

La etiqueta [`set`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/set) no tiene [orientación de uso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/set/info). Dado que según el contexto, `set` puede tener distintos significados, esta etiqueta se está utilizando de manera ambigua.

Considero que sería necesario llegar a un consenso en la utilidad de la etiqueta, escribir una descripción haciendo énfasis en la orientación de uso, y editar (cuando aplique) el etiquetado de las preguntas con esta etiqueta.

He ido pregunta por pregunta mirando el contexto que se le da en cada caso a la etiqueta. Estas son **mis interpretaciones** (pueden ser no precisas) del uso del *tag* en las 36 preguntas:

---

### `set` como "*setter*" (Programación Orientada a Objetos): 16/36

- [No puedo retornar un valor desde una tercera clase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/586487/no-puedo-retornar-un-valor-desde-una-tercera-clase)
- [Python: métodos get y set](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/572044/python-m%c3%a9todos-get-y-set)
- [POO: impresión de valores, sobre los parametros e invocación de metodos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/531569/poo-impresi%c3%b3n-de-valores-sobre-los-parametros-e-invocaci%c3%b3n-de-metodos)
- [¿Por qué mi resultado me da 0?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/516607/por-qu%c3%a9-mi-resultado-me-da-0)
- [Problema con getters y setters en 2 metodos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/513772/problema-con-getters-y-setters-en-2-metodos)
- [Kotlin: Usar setters personalizados en el constructor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/509114/kotlin-usar-setters-personalizados-en-el-constructor)
- [Metodos get and set en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/495078/metodos-get-and-set-en-python)
- [Método para crear promedio General](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/494090/m%c3%a9todo-para-crear-promedio-general)
- [Problemas con atributos privados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/491163/problemas-con-atributos-privados)
- [Usar variables privadas en otra clase NO principal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/465301/usar-variables-privadas-en-otra-clase-no-principal)
- [Problemas con get; set; Windows Form](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/440126/problemas-con-get-set-windows-form)
- [C# Set property desde la clase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/433027/c-set-property-desde-la-clase)
- [como invocar los metodos set y get desde el main](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/311011/como-invocar-los-metodos-set-y-get-desde-el-main)
- [¿Significado del doble guión bajo "__" en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/370137/significado-del-doble-gui%c3%b3n-bajo-en-javascript)
- [Metodo get me regresa un null](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/314739/metodo-get-me-regresa-un-null)
- [¿Se puede setear el valor de un atributo llamando a otra función que no sea set?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/254883/se-puede-setear-el-valor-de-un-atributo-llamando-a-otra-funci%c3%b3n-que-no-sea-set)

---

### `set` como colección de elementos: 11/36

- [Duplicados en tipos de conjuntos HashSet y LinkedHashSet en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/591338/duplicados-en-tipos-de-conjuntos-hashset-y-linkedhashset-en-java)
- [No repetir una String utilizando la función set de Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/550802/no-repetir-una-string-utilizando-la-funci%c3%b3n-set-de-python)
- [Por qué el arreglo actualiza cada elemento cuando actualizo un elemento?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/506580/por-qu%c3%a9-el-arreglo-actualiza-cada-elemento-cuando-actualizo-un-elemento)
- [A veces se crean 2 elementos en vez de 3 en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/436072/a-veces-se-crean-2-elementos-en-vez-de-3-en-python)
- [Operaciones de conjuntos en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/416115/operaciones-de-conjuntos-en-python)
- [Pedir palabras en un prompt, eliminar las repetidas y ordenarlas de la Z a la A con Set()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/405886/pedir-palabras-en-un-prompt-eliminar-las-repetidas-y-ordenarlas-de-la-z-a-la-a)
- [Funcionamiento de Map.set() y sumar el numero de veces que se repite una clave como valor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/405849/funcionamiento-de-map-set-y-sumar-el-numero-de-veces-que-se-repite-una-clave-c)
- [¿Por qué razón mi diccionario es unhasheable? Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/368159/por-qu%c3%a9-raz%c3%b3n-mi-diccionario-es-unhasheable-python)
- [Swift - ¿Cuándo usar un Array y cuándo un Set?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/317266/swift-cu%c3%a1ndo-usar-un-array-y-cu%c3%a1ndo-un-set)
- [set<>* da segmentation fault](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286589/set-da-segmentation-fault)
- [c++ error ‘const class std::vector<Nodo>’ has no member named ‘find’;](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/213124/c-error-const-class-stdvectornodo-has-no-member-named-find)

---

### `set` como operación en `sql` (4/36)

- [insertar valores de una tabla en otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/536388/insertar-valores-de-una-tabla-en-otra)
- [Consulta mysqli que comienza con set @variable me devuelve 0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/483975/consulta-mysqli-que-comienza-con-set-variable-me-devuelve-0)
- [Consulta mysqli que comienza con set @total no se ejecuta en php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/482693/consulta-mysqli-que-comienza-con-set-total-no-se-ejecuta-en-php)
- [Guardar fecha actual en una variable mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/307117/guardar-fecha-actual-en-una-variable-mysql)

---

### `set` en el `cmd` de `Windows` (1/36)

- [Busque el archivo más pequeño y el más grande en cmd y copie la ruta en una variable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/415017/busque-el-archivo-m%c3%a1s-peque%c3%b1o-y-el-m%c3%a1s-grande-en-cmd-y-copie-la-ruta-en-una-vari)

---

### `set` no clasificados (4/36)

- [Tkinter error :( Attribute error: 'Entry' has no attribute 'set', 'get'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/412485/tkinter-error-attribute-error-entry-has-no-attribute-set-get)
- [No puedo usar set en un Text en Tkinter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/506675/no-puedo-usar-set-en-un-text-en-tkinter)
- [¿Como puedo pasar los datos de jframe a una clase para realizar operaciones y despues regresar el resultado al jframe?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/525698/como-puedo-pasar-los-datos-de-jframe-a-una-clase-para-realizar-operaciones-y-de)
- [Como puedo convertir mi data JSON en una clase?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/471586/como-puedo-convertir-mi-data-json-en-una-clase)

---

---

Mi propuesta, posiblemente mejorable, es la siguiente:

- Crear una etiqueta de nombre `setter` para el caso de Programación Orientada a Objetos ([mismo nombre de etiqueta que en la comunidad angloparlante](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/setter/info)).
- Utilizar la etiqueta ya existente [`conjuntos`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conjuntos) para el caso de la colección de elementos.
- No tengo los conocimientos suficientes para opinar para el resto de casos, pero propongo un "reetiquetado" para estos también.
- Finalmente, borraría la etiqueta `set` acabando así con la ambiguedad.

Comment: Gracias por notarlo.. yo por lo menos, debo pensarlo.. cuando una etiqueta sirve para mil cosas, entonces por lo general no sirve para nada...

Comment: Personalmente considero que el problema no es la etiqueta, ya que la etiqueta es un reflejo de lo que se vive hoy en día.... *set* es un término muy utilizado de forma nativa y no nativa en distintas áreas de la programación (lenguajes, base de datos, arquitectura) … por lo tanto la etiqueta tiene variaciones de conceptos dependiente del enfoque de uso. Principalmente *set* se refiere aun un contexto de asignación o establece una cosa en un punto de partida… independientemente del contexto es la orientacion que asume el termino o etiqueta.

Comment: la utilidad de la etiqueta dependera del conocimiento del usuario ... y el enfoque ... debe ir acompañada de otras etiquetas para que tenga sentido.

Comment: Esto no avanzo mucho...  creo que basicamente hay que quemar la etiqueta por no aportar nada....

Comment: Creo que deberíamos definir algunos lineamientos para las etiquetas. Como por ejemplo, eliminar todas las etiquetas que tengan múltiples usos o que no sean: un concepto, un lenguaje o un producto. Creo que las etiquetas no deben ser demasiado generales (como `set`) ni tan específicas (`cmd-set`).

Comment: creo que ya la eliminaron @Mateo ....

Comment: @gbianchi Si ya la quemaron... por qué no la quitan *de las preguntas* ... esto solo provoca que salga ... como etiqueta no creada y me da ansiedad verla en la lista de etiquetas no creadas ... TDA ...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 la etiqueta no se borró. Solamente se eliminó su wiki. Puedes encontrar todas la preguntas con esa etiqueta [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/set). También estaría bueno que pongan en lista negra la etiqueta. Sino alguien podría volver a usarla.

Comment: no tiene sentido usar una etiqueta sin wiki... o que sentido tendria utilizarla en nuevas preguntas ... deberias borrarlas de las preguntas tambien y dejar el sistema completamente limpio en lugar de a medias ... incluso creo que el borrado de las etiquetas tiene mas sentido si se pudiera validar cuantos usuarios siguen una etiqueta ...